# JSF composite components slowing down web application

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component, mojarra

I am using a lot of composite component in my application to avoid redundant code. Some of those component are quite big and containing about 50 to 100 JSF-components. 
The problem that occurs is that - the more of those components I use in one single page - the more it slows down the hole page. We are talking about up to 5 seconds even for small partial ajax request, if I use about 500 to 1000 of those big components on a single page. But for just a few, lets say up to 50, there is no noticeable problem.
I know there has been a bug in previous mojarra versions and there are some topics related to this here on stackoverflow, but I have found nothing for actual mojarra versions.
So, are there still known performance issues related to this? Are there any known workarounds or some kind of best practise checklist to speed pages with composite component?

Comment: Have you considered using MyFaces until Mojarra bugs get fixed?

Comment: What version are you using of mojarra? Also do any of your components getters/setters have any more logic than just a get set element?  Because if ti does it database gets it can get called many many times per life cycle.